# Disable translator for Zend_Form_Element, but not it's validators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-translate

I have a `Zend_Form_Element_Select` object, and about 3k select options. When the customer asked me to look further into optimization possibilities, I did some debug tracing, and noticed, that there were more than 3k calls to `Zend_Form_Element_Multi->_translateValue` and a little less to `Zend_Form_Element_Multi->_translateOption` . I found the option to set `$elem->setDisableTranslator(true)`, which took care of these translations, for which I had no need. But the problem now is, that the error messages are no longer translated.

What I would like to know is, if there is a way to not translate values and options, but translate Validator messages?

I tried this:

```
foreach($operators->getValidators() as $val){
        $val->setDisableTranslator(false);
    }
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any option within the element classes so the simple solution would be extending the `Zend_Form_Element_Select` class with your own. Then you can override the `_translateOptions` method as follows

```
class My_Form_Element_Select extends Zend_Form_Element_Select {

    protected function _translateOption($option,$value) {
        // or add more logic here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you can set some additional logic and options for this scenario, i.e. turn on/off translation for options.

If you want to eliminate this calls all together you will have to override the `getMultiOption()` or `getMultiOptions()` which are calling `_translateOption()`.

Comment: Thanks! In the end, didn't need to do this, but this would have worked